# Can you take a disbursement from your HSA account long after a procedure?

Tags: united-states, hsa

Assuming that an hsa qualified health care plan is in effect:

Can you do the following?

1. Get a procedure that is covered and pay out of pocket for it
2. After the procedure save up money in your HSA
3. Take a disbursement from the HSA account to pay you back once the money is saved in your HSA

Comment: The marked duplicate answers the question, this benefit of the HSA can be leveraged with investments over many years, wrote a bit about that here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110771/minimizing-medical-costs-with-hsa/110772#110772

Comment: Note: What the duplicate question doesn’t make clear is that you can only take a reimbursement for a medical expense that is incurred after your HSA is established (even if there isn’t enough money in it at the time). Your question assumes that “an HSA qualified health care plan is in effect,” but that is not the same thing as ensuring that the HSA account itself exists, which would need to happen before the medical procedure.

Comment: Related: [I spend more on healthcare than my HSA can cover right now. How to handle reimbursements?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/77094/10997)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help navigating this